# Regular expression validating email with specific domain/subdomain

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate email with specific domain name and with/without a subdomain, using javascript.

```
abcdefgh@abc.com              - valid
abcdefgh@subdomain.abc.com    - valid
abcdefgh@abc.com.au           - invalid
abcdefgh@subdomain.abc.com.au - invalid
abcdefgh@subdomain.subdomain.abc.com - invalid
abcdefgh@subdomain.subdomain.abc.com.au - invalid
```

The reg exp that I used.

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,}+@[a-zA-Z]{1,}\.abc\.com$
```

doesn't return the desired results. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `{1,}+` doesn't make sense, but you should actually ask a question.

Comment: Why restrict the characters before `@` to just letters?

Comment: we can replace that to include numbers as well. [a-zA-Z1-9]

Comment: {1,}+ is to have 1 or more letters before @sign

Comment: `{1,}` means the same thing as `+`. They're both quantifiers. You can't have both in a row.

Comment: the regexp that I came up with- ^[^@]+@([a-zA-Z1-9]+\.)?abc\.com$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the subdomain part as optional.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+@(?:[a-zA-Z]+\.abc|\.abc)\.com$
```

or

```
^[a-zA-Z]+@(?:[a-zA-Z]+\.)?abc\.com$
```